# How to extract value from Json where multiple child objects units and only specific value I need to extract

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract tId where "sType= 7"

I've tried to extract all ids from the response and use them randomly, but it doesn't work this way.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) Expressions in the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

1. To extract a random unit id:

   ```
   $..units.*.id
   ```
2. To extract a random child for the given unit:

   ```
   $..units[?(@.id == '${unit}')].children.*.id
   ```
3. To extract random content from the child:

   ```
   $..children[?(@.id == '${child}')].contents.*.id
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JSONPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of errors in JSON. I assumed some tags and fixed it. Refer screenshot below to form your json path

[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: I have Updated Json I want Extract tId where Stype is 7 form multple childs